# Unable to implement __lt__ (less than) method to sort a list of class objects

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to use _lt__ method to compare class objects and sort accordingly.But haven't been able to do so far

```
class Test:

    def __init__(self,x):
        self.x = x

    def __lt__(self,other):
        return self.x < other.x

t1 = Test(10)
t2 = Test(12)
lis = [t1,t2]
lis.sort()
print(lis)
```

I am getting output as

```
[<__main__.Test object at 0x7fd4c592fb70>, <__main__.Test object at 0x7fd4c592fb38>]
```

I thought maybe I need to give a string representation to the object.So I did

```
def __str__(self):
    return "{}".format(self.x)
```

Still I am getting the same output

```
[<__main__.Test object at 0x7f212594bac8>, <__main__.Test object at 0x7f212594bc50>]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are doing almost everything right; the thing is just that objects inside a list are represented by `__repr__` and not `__str__`:

```
class Test:

    def __init__(self,x):
        self.x = x

    def __lt__(self,other):
        return self.x < other.x

    def __repr__(self):
        return "{}".format(self.x)

t1 = Test(10)
t2 = Test(12)
lis = [t1,t2]
lis.sort()
print(lis)  # [10, 12]
```

Comment: Oh glad to know that!Thanks!